# SQL SERVER equivalent of dbengine.compactdatabase

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, dao

I am now working on converting a vb6 Application to newer vb.net technology. 
In the old vb6 App, they use MSAccess DAO, and i have to convert it all for it to work on SQL server - using ADO.net sqlClient.

i managed to get it done 99% but there is one more thing left.

In the old Application, they use dbengine.compactdatabase after every period of time(6 months to 1 year) to maintain the MSAccess DBes.

I wonder if there is any SQL server equivalent to DAO dbengine.compactdatabase? This program have a seperate Backup Function to backup its database, this dbengine.compactdatabase is for maintain and repair purpose.

I do not have much knowledge about DB stuff, sorry if i made a bad question.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: There's no reason for such a thing. SQL Server is a *server*, not a single file database like Access that needs compacting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i can just delete it. This program now can run 100% same as the old one. But it 's my curiousity, and i just want to complete this perfectly.

Comment: No you can't just delete the database. I *strongly* suggest you find a SQL Server course before you destroy production data. Microsoft itself offers free introductory courses and through the free Visual Studio Dev Essentials program you can get 3 months free access to Pluralsight courses.

Comment: I imagine they meant delete the obsolete command rather than the database

Comment: Thank you for sugestion, and sorry for my bad English. I mean i can get rid of this dbengine.compactdatabase things and find another way to maintain databases.

Comment: I'm assuming `compactdatabase` is equivalent to SQL Server's Shrink database command, [this is something you really want to avoid.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57179040/3094533)

Comment: Thank you mr.Zohar Peled, It really help me out. I thought about it before also, but as you pointed out that shrink database can cause fragmentation. I cannot take the risk, maybe i should just get rid of this feature. Thank you for your answer!